# Single Redirection Rule for Pages and Archive links

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am trying to find pretty URL solution for url parameters.

**Consider this url set**

```
http://example.com?token=foo
http://example.com/pagename?token=foo
http://example.com/parent/childpage?token=foo
http://example.com/category/bar?token=foo
..
```

**My Previous Code Example**

```
add_action('template_redirect', function(){

    if(!isset($_GET['token])){
         return;
    }

    // run code

});
```

Need to move the whole thing into WordPress Pretty url.

**Example pretty Urls with parameter**

```
http://example.com/foo
http://example.com/pagename/foo
http://example.com/parent/childpage/foo
http://example.com/category/bar/foo
..
```

For a page this is the working Rewrite rule

```
add_rewrite_rule("([^/]*)/foo", 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&'. foo .'=1', 'top');
```

Which doesn't seem to work for nested child pages. So for child pages upto 2 nested page. I have to add

```
add_rewrite_rule("([^/]*)/foo", 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&foo=1', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule("([^/]*)/([^/]*)/foo", 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&foo=1', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule("([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/foo", 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]/$matches[2]/$matches[3]&foo=1', 'top');
```

Is there any possible way to do it on single line of code so all pages, nested or parent, posts, archive links?

My end goal is to pass the extra `foo` parameters. Other WordPress query vars remains same.

**Full Gist for you to look into more details** https://gist.github.com/prionkor/ef2e6b24d8d5561b4ad7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add a parameter to all url of WordPress [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) is more appropriate.

I needed to add `/foo` after all URL so `add_rewrite_endpoint("foo", EP_ALL);` did the trick.